# Upstart Ruby version issue

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, upstart, ruby

I am trying to get Upstart to fire up Sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deploying-to-Ubuntu).  I can manually start it but the same command fails in the Upstart script.  I have piped the output of the script to a log file:

Piped the output of my script to a log:

```
usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/staging/current/bin/sidekiq:14:in `<main>'
```

So I have:

```
$ which -a ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ rbenv versions
system
* 2.2.3 (set by /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/version)
```

My rails app is using 2.2.3 so can I just delete the 1.9.1 version manually or via rbenv (rbenv uninstall system)?